# (Swift) Move Button To Random Location With Exceptions

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to move a label to a random location which I have been able to do so using this code.

```
let buttonWidth = self.samea.frame.width
        let buttonHeight = self.samea.frame.height

        // Find the width and height of the enclosing view
        let viewWidth = self.samea.superview!.bounds.width
        let viewHeight = self.samea.superview!.bounds.height

        // Compute width and height of the area to contain the button's center
        let xwidth = viewWidth - buttonWidth
        let yheight = viewHeight - buttonHeight

        // Generate a random x and y offset
        let xoffset = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(xwidth)))
        let yoffset = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(yheight)))

        // Offset the button's center by the random offsets.
        self.newButtonX = xoffset + buttonWidth/2
        self.newButtonY = yoffset + buttonHeight/2
        self.samea.center.x = self.newButtonX!
        self.samea.center.y = self.newButtonY!
```

The problem is, I have some buttons and labels on the storyboard and I do not want the button to spawn on top of those. Not sure how to do that. Any help is appreciated !

Comment: Can you add image what exactly happening.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/rInvX @VirajPadsala I have those two pink buttons near the bottom. My other button randomly appears on any location on the screen. I want it to avoid contact with the two pink buttons when it appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array property of all the `UIButton` and `UILabel` outlets that you have, populate it in your `viewDidLoad(_:)` method. Then when you're generating your random values, you can put them in a while loop and cycle through the values.

Something like this.

```
let buttonsAndLabels = [UIView]()
var xoffset: CGFloat
var yoffset: CGFloat
var isOccupied = true
while isOccupied {
  xoffset = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(xwidth)))
  yoffset = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(yheight)))
  let frame = CGRect(x: xoffset, y: yoffset, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)

  isOccupied = false
  for view in buttonsAndLabels {
    if view.frame.intersects(frame) {
      isOccupied = true
    }
  }
}
```